# Как исправить ошибку при запуске процедуры: "PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to"?

Tags: node.js, oracle, plsql

Как исправить эту ошибку:

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_DATA_INFO'
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Получаю ее когда запускаю процедуру:

```
PROCEDURE get_data_info (
  p_ticker       VARCHAR2,
  p_acronym      VARCHAR2,
  p_sort         VARCHAR2,
  p_call_source  VARCHAR2,
  p_data     OUT REF_CRS);
```

Node.js код:

```
sql = 'begin get_data_info(:p_ticker, :p_acronym, :p_sort, :p_call_source, :p_data); end;';
const ticker_data = {
    p_ticker: '',
    p_acronym: '',
    p_sort: '',
    p_call_source: '',
    p_data: ''
};
data = { p_ticker: 'AAPL', p_data: ':output'};
binds  = Object.assign({}, ticker_data, data);
        
options = {
    outFormat: oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT,  
};
result = await connection.execute(sql, binds, options);
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [PLS-00306 when calling Oracle stored procedure in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63780678/6571020) от участника [@siddhartha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3003651/siddhartha)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/63780678

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместе с [@0xdb](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/217579/0xdb) провели [рефакторинг кода](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113634/discussion-between-norbornen-and-0xdb), предложенного в ответе [@Christopher Jones](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1183549).

Код полностью рабочий, проверен на [macos](/questions/tagged/macos), [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) v14.10.0, драйвер [node-oracledb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb) v5.0.0.

```
create or replace procedure get_data_info (
    p_ticker       varchar2,
    p_acronym      varchar2,
    p_sort         varchar2,
    p_call_source  varchar2,
    p_data     out sys_refcursor) as
begin
    open p_data for select 1 id, 'memo' memo, sysdate created from dual;
end;
```

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');

const dbConfig = { user: 'me', password: 'me', connectString: 'localhost/pdb1' };

(async () => await run())();

async function run() {
    let connection;

    try {

        connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);

        const sql = `
            begin
                get_data_info(:p_ticker,:p_acronym,:p_sort,:p_call_source,:p_data);
            end;`;
        const binds = {
            p_ticker: 'AAPL',
            p_data: { dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.CURSOR },
            p_acronym: undefined,
            p_sort: undefined,
            p_call_source: undefined
        };

        const options = {
            outFormat: oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT,  
        };

        const result = await connection.execute(sql, binds, options);

        const resultSet = result.outBinds.p_data;

        let row;
        while (row = await resultSet.getRow()) {
            console.log(row);
        }

        await resultSet.close();

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } finally {
        if (connection) {
            try {
                await connection.close();
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Результат выполнения

> { ID: 1, MEMO: 'memo', CREATED: 2020-10-02T10:55:07.000Z }

---

Разделы документации, которые стоит изучить в связи с этим вопросом:

- [REF CURSOR Bind Parameters](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#refcursors)
  For an OUT bind, the resulting bind variable becomes a ResultSet, allowing rows to be fetched using getRow() or getRows()
- [IN Bind Parameters](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#-211-in-bind-parameters) Bind by Name

---

Для пользователей `process.platform === 'darwin'`

В целом, установка драйвера описана в [соответствующем разделе документации](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#instosx), но её можно упростить, установив `instantclient` с помощью менеджера пакетов [homebrew](/questions/tagged/homebrew)

```
brew tap InstantClientTap/instantclient
brew install instantclient-basic
```

Answer (score 3):

Предполагаю, что `REF_CRS` является `REF CURSOR`, и проблема заключается в определении `p_data` в объекте параметра связывания.  Нужно дать ему тип и направление:

```
p_data: {dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.CURSOR}
```

Пдробней в документции к `node-oracledb` в главе [REF CURSOR Bind Parameters](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#refcursors).

---

Вот как выглядит рабочий пример:
SQL:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE get_data_info (
  p_ticker       VARCHAR2,
  p_acronym      VARCHAR2,
  p_sort         VARCHAR2,
  p_call_source  VARCHAR2,
  p_data     OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) as
begin
  open p_data for select * from dual;
end;
/
```

Node.js:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const dbConfig = { user: 'me', password: 'me', connectString: 'localhost/pdb1' };

if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
    oracledb.initOracleClient({libDir: '/Users/cjones/instantclient_19_3'});
}

let sql, binds, options, result;
async function run() {
    let connection;
    try {
        connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);
        sql = 'begin get_data_info(:p_ticker,:p_acronym,:p_sort,:p_call_source,:p_data); end;';
        const ticker_data = {
            p_ticker: '',
            p_acronym: '',
            p_sort: '',
            p_call_source: '',
            p_data: ''
        };
        const data = { p_ticker: 'AAPL', p_data: {dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.CURSOR}};
        const binds = Object.assign({}, ticker_data, data);   

        result = await connection.execute(sql, binds, options);
        const resultSet = result.outBinds.p_data;
        let row;
        while ((row = await resultSet.getRow())) {
            console.log(row);
        }
        await resultSet.close(); 
    
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } finally {
        if (connection) {
            try {
                await connection.close();
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        }
    }
}
run();
```

---

PS (*Прим.ред. на основе комментариев*): такая запись подстановочных переменных будет проще и понятней:

```
const binds = {
    p_ticker: 'AAPL', 
    p_acronym: undefined,
    p_sort: undefined,
    p_call_source: undefined,
    p_data: {dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.CURSOR}
};
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63785181) от участника [@Christopher Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4799035/christopher-jones)</sub>

Comment: интереса ради, а зачем `ticker_data` заполняется пустыми строками и вообще как оно связано с запросом?

Comment: @nörbörnën ticker_data это только местозаполнитель. В нём главное имена подстановочных переменныx для процедуры. Пустые строки в Oracle это null. То, что будет переддано как значения аргументов берётся из data, перепишет пустые строки когда bind объект создаётся. Что вы имеете ввиду: вообще как оно связано с запросом? Это подстановочные переменные.

Comment: @nörbörnën Вообще конечно, можно записать проще литералом при вызове. По видимому, автор часть кода скопировал из вопроса и не попытался его улучшить. Он продукт менеджер, а не разработчик, подзабыл кое-чего немного.

Comment: я просто не понял: 1) почему ticker_data инитится пустыми строками, если можно просто не инитить; 2) вижу объявление одноимённых ключей в оракловской процедуре, но не вижу их использования

Comment: @nörbörnën 1) А как не инитить? Там же надо что-то написать, хотя бы null. 2) О содержимом процедуры в вопросе речи не идёт. Он передаёт туда только одно входное значение и одно выходное, остальные три  - NULL, как и было в вопросе. ПС Сейчас не могу проверить код, как появится возможность, подрихтую чюток, чтобы было понятней.

Comment: я затупил с вопросами. чехарда с ключами в байнде связана с формированием "псевдо-sql" для вызова процедуры (`:p_ticker`) и, видимо, передача undefined там не проканает

Comment: @nörbörnën У процедуры нет параметров по-умолчанию, т.е. надо передавать все пять, ни больше, ни меньше. Что вы имеете ввиду: _передача undefined_? Записать так: `{par1: undefined, ..., parN: undefined}`, может и прокатит не пробовал.

Comment: если "прокатит" то в существовании переменной `const ticker_data` нет никакого смысла, что возвращает нас к моему первому сообщению.

Comment: @nörbörnën Как уже написал - _автор часть кода скопировал из вопроса и не попытался его улучшить_. В ticker_data необходимости нет, можно просто все пять параметров прямо в вызове литералом объекта указать, будет короче и понятней.

Comment: @nörbörnën Добавил PS. Так вы имели ввиду?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113634/discussion-between-norbornen-and-0xdb).

Answer (score 1):

Вариант для [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript):

```
create or replace procedure get_data_info (
    p_ticker       varchar2,
    p_acronym      varchar2,
    p_sort         varchar2,
    p_call_source  varchar2,
    p_data     out sys_refcursor) as
begin
    open p_data for select 1 id, 'memo' memo, sysdate created from dual;
end;
```

```
import * as OracleDB from 'OracleDB';

const dbConfig: OracleDB.ConnectionAttributes = {
    user: 'me',
    password: 'me',
    connectString: 'localhost/pdb1'
};

class ConnectDAO {
    public async ConnectionDB(): Promise<OracleDB.Connection> {
        return OracleDB.getConnection(dbConfig);
    }
    public async fetchData<T>(
        connection: OracleDB.Connection,
        sql: string,
        bindParams: OracleDB.BindParameters = {},
        options: OracleDB.ExecuteOptions = {}
    ): Promise<OracleDB.Result<T>> {
        return connection.execute<T>(sql, bindParams, options);
    }
}

async function connectAndExecute() {
    let connectDao = new ConnectDAO();
    try {
        const connection = await connectDao.ConnectionDB();
        
        const sql = `
        begin
            get_data_info(:p_ticker,:p_acronym,:p_sort,:p_call_source,:p_data);
        end;`;

        const binds: OracleDB.BindParameters = {
            p_ticker: 'AAPL',
            p_acronym: undefined,
            p_sort: undefined,
            p_call_source: undefined,
            p_data: {
                dir: OracleDB.BIND_OUT,
                type: OracleDB.CURSOR
            }
        };

        const options: OracleDB.ExecuteOptions = {
            outFormat: OracleDB.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT
        };

        const results = await connectDao.fetchData<{p_data: OracleDB.ResultSet<Record<string, any>>}>(connection, sql, binds, options);

        const resultSet = results.outBinds.p_data;

        let row: Record<string, any>;
        while (row = await resultSet.getRow()) {
          console.log(row);
        }

        await resultSet.close();
        await connection.close();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`error caught ${err}`);
    }
}

connectAndExecute();
```