# Что необходимо указать в connectString для подключения к базе данных Oracle?

Tags: sql, node.js, oracle

Ситуация следующая: мне необходимо реализовать подключение БД, которая находится на моей локальной машине к Node.js проекту с помощью `oracledb`.

В процессе изучения удалось дойти до метода `getConnect`, у которого есть 3 атрибута. С `name` и `password` вопросов нет, а вот с `connectString` вопросы всё-таки возникли.

Что именно требуется указать в `connectString` ?

Прошу по возможности показать и пример заполнения.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1185242/2659

Comment: `const dbConfig = {user: "hr", password: 'hr_schema_password', connectString: "mydbmachine.example.com:1721/orclpdb1"};`. 
В этом примере `mydbmachine.example.com` - Host, `1721` - Port, `orclpdb1` - Service Name,

Comment: пример взят из [документации](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#connectionstrings) к модулю oracledb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const connection = await oracledb.getConnection(
{
    user          : "user",
    password      : passwd,
    connectString : "dbserver.domain.com:1521/pdb1"
});
```

Где `connectString` имеет следующую структуру ([подробнее в оф.док.](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connectionstrings)):

- dbserver.domain.com - Полное или неполное имя машины, или IP, на которой работает прослушиватель БД (*listener*). В локальном окружении должна быть возможность разрешения имени в IP. Для локальной машины: localhost или 127.0.0.1.
- :1521 - Порт, который сконфигурирован в прослушивателе, по умолчанию 1521.
- /pdb1 - имя сервиса, с которым прослушиватель обслуживает запросы на подключение.
  **Важно:** это не имя БД (*db_name*) и не SID, это имя сервиса (*service_name*), присвоенное конкретной БД. В течении ~1 мин. после старта БД регистрирует себя на прослушивателе - "посылай ко мне все запросы на подсоединение с этим именем".

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к принятому ответу.

[oracledb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb) - низкоуровневая библиотека и, обычно, в разработке используются более высокоуровневые библиотеки - query builder или orm.

Примеры демонстрируют запрос к таблице DEPARTMENTS схемы HR.

#### Пример работы [oracledb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb):

```js
const oracledb = require('oracledb');

(async () => {
  let connection;

  try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
      user: 'hr',
      password: 'hr_schema_password',
      connectString: 'mydbmachine.example.com:1721/orclpdb1'
    });

    const { rows: items } = await connection.execute(
      `SELECT department_id, department_name
        FROM hr.departments WHERE department_id > :id`,
      [100],
      {
        outFormat: oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT,
        maxRows: 2
      }
    );

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      try {
        await connection.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

```bsh
[
  { DEPARTMENT_ID: 110, DEPARTMENT_NAME: 'Accounting' },
  { DEPARTMENT_ID: 120, DEPARTMENT_NAME: 'Treasury' }
]
```

#### Пример с использование SQL query builder [knex](https://knexjs.org/):

```js
const { default: Knex } = require('knex');

(async () => {
  let knex;

  try {
    knex = await Knex({
      client: 'oracledb',
      connection: {
        user: 'hr',
        password: 'hr_schema_password',
        connectString: 'mydbmachine.example.com:1721/orclpdb1'
      },
      wrapIdentifier: (value, origImpl) => origImpl(value.toUpperCase())
    });

    const qb = knex.queryBuilder()
      .table('departments').withSchema('hr')
      .where('department_id', '>', 100)
      .select(['department_id', 'department_name'])
      .limit(2);
    const items = await qb.select();

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (knex) {
      try {
        await knex.destroy();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

```bsh
[
  { DEPARTMENT_ID: 110, DEPARTMENT_NAME: 'Accounting' },
  { DEPARTMENT_ID: 120, DEPARTMENT_NAME: 'Treasury' }
]
```

#### Пример с использование orm [typeorm](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm)[typeorm](/questions/tagged/typeorm):

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { createConnection, Entity, Column, PrimaryColumn, getRepository, MoreThan, JoinColumn, ManyToOne, LessThan } from 'typeorm';

@Entity('DEPARTMENTS')
class Department {
  @PrimaryColumn('number')
  DEPARTMENT_ID: number;

  @Column('varchar', {length: 30})
  DEPARTMENT_NAME: string;

  @Column('number')
  MANAGER_ID: number;

  @Column('number')
  LOCATION_ID: number;

  @ManyToOne((type) => Employee)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'MANAGER_ID' })
  MANAGER: Employee;
}

@Entity('EMPLOYEES')
class Employee {
  @PrimaryColumn('number')
  EMPLOYEE_ID: number;

  @Column('varchar', {length: 20})
  FIRST_NAME: string;

  @Column('varchar', {length: 25})
  LAST_NAME: string;
}


(async () => {
  const connection = await createConnection({
    type: 'oracle',
    username: 'hr',
    password: 'hr_schema_password',
    schema: 'HR',
    synchronize: false,
    logging: true,
    extra: {
      connectString: 'mydbmachine.example.com:1721/orclpdb1'
    },
    entities: [
      Department, Employee
    ]
  });

  try {
    let items = await getRepository(Department).find({
      where: {
        DEPARTMENT_ID: LessThan(100)
      },
      relations: [ 'MANAGER' ],
      take: 2
    });
    console.log(items);

    const qb = getRepository(Department).createQueryBuilder('d');
    qb.innerJoinAndMapOne(`${qb.alias}.MANAGER`, Employee, 'e', 'd.MANAGER_ID = e.EMPLOYEE_ID')
      .limit(2);
    items = await qb.getMany();
    console.log(items);
    
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }

  await connection.close();

})();
```

```bsh
[
  Department {
    DEPARTMENT_ID: 10,
    DEPARTMENT_NAME: 'Administration',
    MANAGER_ID: 200,
    LOCATION_ID: 1700,
    MANAGER: Employee {
      EMPLOYEE_ID: 200,
      FIRST_NAME: 'Jennifer',
      LAST_NAME: 'Whalen'
    }
  },
  Department {
    DEPARTMENT_ID: 20,
    DEPARTMENT_NAME: 'Marketing',
    MANAGER_ID: 201,
    LOCATION_ID: 1800,
    MANAGER: Employee {
      EMPLOYEE_ID: 201,
      FIRST_NAME: 'Michael',
      LAST_NAME: 'Hartstein'
    }
  }
]

[
  Department {
    DEPARTMENT_ID: 10,
    DEPARTMENT_NAME: 'Administration',
    MANAGER_ID: 200,
    LOCATION_ID: 1700,
    MANAGER: Employee {
      EMPLOYEE_ID: 200,
      FIRST_NAME: 'Jennifer',
      LAST_NAME: 'Whalen'
    }
  },
  Department {
    DEPARTMENT_ID: 20,
    DEPARTMENT_NAME: 'Marketing',
    MANAGER_ID: 201,
    LOCATION_ID: 1800,
    MANAGER: Employee {
      EMPLOYEE_ID: 201,
      FIRST_NAME: 'Michael',
      LAST_NAME: 'Hartstein'
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Ну совсем бедного ТС в информации потопили ;)

Comment: @0xdb я хотел написать ответ, на который бы мог ссылался в будущих вопросах. Да и ТС, кмк, [тонет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1279502/2659) в другом месте, которое легко решилось бы механизмом миграций

Comment: Там не понятно в чём он тонет, может в 100 строках заблудился. У него обычная форма описания задачи с десятком витиеватых предложений вместо примера с парой строк кода.